# The Download file for IOS debug build from codenameone is zip not IPA

Tags: codenameone

I am successfully using codenameone netbeans.
 After successfully compiling my app for send iOS debug build to codenameone and successfully completed, the downloaded file for MyApplication.IPA is zip not IPA.
So please help for this, for how to download the file as IPA not a zip file?
Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't build zips in iOS targets. IPA files are technically zips in much the same way as JAR files are zips. But you shouldn't extract them or anything like that.

I'm guessing your browser detects the file format is a zip and is being stupid about it. I suggest trying a different browser.